# Post to a Facebook page as the page not an admin user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post a message to a Facebook page, but as the page - not as my own Facebook profile. I'm using version 5 of the Facebook PHP SDK.  Any ideas how to achieve this? My code below posts to the Facebook page fine, but it posts the message as my own profile not the page.

```
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/src/facebook-sdk-v5/');
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'appid',
    'app_secret' => 'secretid',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}


if (isset($accessToken)) {

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    $linkData = [
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message',
    ];

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/294673057366719/feed', $linkData, $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    echo 'Posted with id: '.$graphNode['id'];

} else {

    $permissions = ['publish_pages', 'manage_pages'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://app.co.uk:8888/facebook/', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Log in</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is in use **right access token**.

You need generate access token for your page. How to achieve it:

1. You need an user which is admin of page you want to post to
2. Generate access token for this user with permissions: publis_actions, manage_pages
3. Now exchange this short lived access token for long lived access token
4. Finally you can call api request /USER_ID/accounts. In result find page you want and copy access token (**important:** for this call use generated long lived access token from step 3!)

Now use this token to post on page wall as page.

Detailed flow for exchange short for live access token is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens. For all calls you can use facebook Graph API Explorer here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got the access token for my page by:

- Getting the 'short-lived' access token for my Facebook page here: 
  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cabout&version=v2.4
- I then passed the 'short-lived' token to this URL to return a long-lived token:
  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=clientid&client_secret=secretid&fb_exchange_token=shorttoken

You now have a non-expiring access token for your Facebook page